# Conversion to Lamar - Registration - What's the equivalent of this code that uses StructureMap?

Tags: .net, lamar

I'm migrating an ASP.NET application to .NET5 and have come across the following code that uses StructureMap...

```
For<ICache>().AlwaysUnique().Singleton().HttpContextScoped().Add<RedisCache>()
```

We are using Lamar in the new application; what's the equivalent code to replace `.AlwaysUnique().Singleton().HttpContextScoped()`?

Comment: Don't `.AlwaysUnique().Singleton()` contradict themselves?

Comment: @mxmissile, indeed they do, this is code I've picked up as part of a migration project and is a bit odd! Having had some comms with Jeremy Miller (Lamar author) he has confirmed that the last one wins, as you would expect. Code has now been adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Having had some comms with Jeremy Miller (Lamar author) he has confirmed that the last one wins, in the this case it would be HttpContextScoped (or Scoped in Lamar).